# Active Directory two user with same permissions, one doesn't have permisions to give admin privileges

Tags: windows, permissions, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, system-administration

i've the following scenario:

In the company almost part of the computers works in domain. there is two admins with absolutely all permisions. Obviously, when a software is required in one of the computers one of the sysadmins must go to put his credentials and password.

So here starts the problem: with one of the admins everything works normally, but with the other user it's impossible. it says that the operation requires permissions elevation, and i insist that both users have exactly the same permissions.

Anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I understand this.  The first admin has no issues installing software, but the second admin does have issues (User Account Control Dialog box popping up).  In what way have you determined they have the same permissions?  Rather than answer that, just run through this checklist until you (or they) find the difference between their privileges and then correct it.

1. Compare the group memberships of their two accounts.  One may be a Domain Admin, while the other might actually not be one, thus accounting for the UAC dialog box popping up.
2. If the above shows no differences, then compare a Resultant Set of Policy report between the both of them.  This means when the first admin logs in, have him/her run this command:   `gpresult /H C:\Admin1.html`

When the 2nd admin logs in, run a fresh report for him/her using `gpresult /H C:\Admin2.html`, then compare that to the first report, and act on any difference you see related to permissions: